# Counting the number of relations

Tags: qgis, count, one-to-many, relation

In QGIS I created a one-to-many relation between a polygon layer and a non-geometry table, so it has multiple lines for each feature in the polygon layer. My question now is how can I count how many rows were related?

For example, let's suppose the table has 44.000 rows, and I have 26.000 polygon features (each with its own id). If it were a one-to-one relation I know it would've been 26.000 relations, but since it's a one-to-many a polygon can have 2 or more rows related with it. How could I know how many rows were related then?

Answer (score 3):

You can use "Statistics by Categories" on the related table. I use plot_uuid as Field(s) with categories:

[image]

Comment: This is nice, but it does not solve my problem considering (for what I tested) that it only counts the same occurrences of a value in one field in a layer. But it doesn't acknowledge the relation situation, in a way that I can't know how many hows were related. For example, in my non_geometry layer when I used the Statistics by Categories the function counted all the fields values that I used to create the relation despite they were related or not, still letting me in the dark with how many of them were in fact present in the polygon layer.